# How to only select the SQL row with the MAX id in this join?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to get the record with the MAX id from this joined table, but I only need the top row to be joined with the main query on this subquery. How can I limit the subquery to only return one row? Previously the tran_state MAX was being returned which did not work correctly.

```
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
     tran_id
     , MAX(id) AS max_tran_id
     , MAX(DATETIME(created, 'America/New_York')) AS max_tran_created
     , tran_state
   FROM `prod.tran` 
   GROUP BY tran_id
   ) data ON t.id = data.tran_id
```

I attempted to modify the query like so but the tran_state is coming back as null.

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
    tran_state, 
    tran_id 
    FROM `prod.tran` WHERE ID IN ( 
    SELECT
    MAX(ID)
    FROM `prod.tran` trans 
    WHERE trans.tran_id = transaction_id)
    ) data ON t.id = data.tran_id
```

Comment: You could use order by and limit the rows returned to 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions:

```
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.tran_id ORDER BY t.id DESC) as seqnum
 FROM `prod.tran` t
) data
ON t.id = data.tran_id AND t.seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `prod.tran`
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM `prod.tran`
    GROUP BY tran_id
) a
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but it's returning null for the tran_state for some reason. I added the new subquery version to my question.

Comment: @J.J. Does the inner query return something?